# PowerBuilder 8 - No menu items

Tags: powerbuilder

We have a program developed in PowerBuilder 8 that displays a menu of operations each associated with a different target. It works fine in our production environment. But in the QA environment the menu items do not appear. We tried copying our production environment to QA and it still does not work.

I understand this question may be too vague but I was wondering if anyone has encountered anything similar or would have any suggestions on where to look.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Vague indeed. Some ideas: is the menu dynamically generated? Does it shows some icons? Is the application located on a file server? For both last points, it could be relative to an access rights issue or a missing source. Look in the source if the menu should always been displayed and if not what is the missing condition when the menu is missing.

Comment: If you're app is PFC-based (look for libraries that start with PFC, like pfcmain.pbl), you might want to look to see if it is using the data-driven security modules. One of the options is to turn the controls invisible. That would explain the differences connecting to different databases (or for that matter, with different users). Look for tables that start with security_, like security_info.